# Uncheck Generate automatic URL alias problem

Tags: 7

When I add new content I uncheck generate automatic url, but below, the Url Alias text field where I want to add custom url is still disabled. I'm not able to write my custom url there.

Comment: Check Permissions.

Comment: thanks you but permission is ok. i'm admin all permission is checked this not cause this.

Comment: it maybe sounds easy but check the console for js errors, it could be an error causing this if Pyone answer is not the solution

Comment: Check in console of your browser if any js file is creating conflict.

Comment: This is an existing bug: https://www.drupal.org/node/936222. Try applying the patch there.

Comment: PathAuto Persistance Module should fix this issue: https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto_persist

Answer (score 0):

Check if "Path" module is enabled.  If not, enable it.  I think it is enabled by default.

And go to admin/people/permissions and check "Administer URL aliases" under "Path" section.

Comment: thanks but path module enabled and permission is ok this not cause this

Comment: i'm able to write custom url using firebug edit html value="" :) but this is bad method. you think what cause disable. in console there's no javascript or another errors?